# exception handling in the implemented method

Tags: java, interface, exception

The code below gives a checked error to `throws Exception`:

```
import java.io.IOException;

interface some {
    void ss99() throws IOException;
}

public class SQL2 implements some {
    @Override
    public void ss99 () throws Exception {}
// ...
}
```

while the one below compiles fine:

```
import java.io.IOException;

interface some {
    void ss99() throws IOException;
}

public class SQL2 implements some {
    @Override
    public void ss99 () throws NullPointerException {}
// ...
}
```

On what logic is Java doing this-- any ideas?

TIA.

Comment: NullPointerException isn't a checked exception.

Answer (score 1):

The `throws` keyword indicates that a method or constructor *can* throw an exception, although it doesn't have to.

Let's start with your second snippet

```
interface some {
    void ss99() throws IOException;
}

public class SQL2 implements some {
    @Override
    public void ss99 () throws NullPointerException {}
}
```

Consider

```
some ref = getSome();
try {
    ref.ss99();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle
}
```

All you have to work with is with your interface `some`. We (the compiler) don't know the actual implementation of the object it is referencing. As such, we have to make sure to handle any `IOException` that *may* be thrown.

In the case of

```
SQL2 ref = new SQL2();
ref.ss99();
```

you're working with the actual implementation. This implementation guarantees that it will never throw an `IOException` (by not declaring it). You therefore don't have to deal with it. You also don't have to deal with `NullPointerException` because it is an unchecked exception.

---

Regarding your first snippet, slightly changed

```
interface some {
    void ss99() throws IOException;
}

public class SQL2 implements some {
    @Override
    public void ss99 () throws Exception { throw new SQLException(); }
}
```

Consider

```
some ref = new SQL2();
try {
    ref.ss99();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle
}
```

So although you are handling the exception declared in the interface, you would be letting a checked exception, `SQLException`, escape unhandled. The compiler cannot allow this.

An overriden method must be declared to throw the same exception (as the parent) or one of its subclasses.